# Distribution of 2nd smallest eigenvalue in an random graph

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

In a random graph $G(n, p)$, is there any result formalizing the distribution of the 2nd-smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$? 
$$
P(\lambda_2 \geq x)
$$

Comment: Is this the adjacency eigenvalue or the Laplacian eigenvalue? Assuming you mean the Laplacian, $\lambda_2$ is zero if and only if the graph is disconnected, so at the very least you're asking for an estimate of the probability of the graph being connected. This is a nontrivial fact about a random graph, so you might get a better answer if you narrow down the distribution family you're talking about.